# How to evaluate $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,1)}\tan^{-1}(y/x)$?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

> $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,1)}\tan^{-1}(y/x)$$

I substituted $y=mx$ and the limit came out to be $\tan^{-1}(m)$.
As the limit depends on $m$ and changes whenever we change $m$, the limit at $(0,1)$ does not exist.
Is my method correct?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773). This will make it more clear as to what you are asking.

Comment: Hi thanks for editing my question . I will try to avoid these mistakes in future. Can you help me with my question?

Comment: :-) Just be patient and you may find answers.

Comment: Your method is not correct. $y=mx$ isn't a path through $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is somewhat unclear, as $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,1)}y/x$ does not exist.

A simple approach would be to consider different paths that go to $(0,1)$. Mainly, I recommend trying

$y=x+1$

As $x\to0^+$ and $x\to0^-$, the limits come out to be $\pi/2$ and $-\pi/2$ respectively.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain how using y=x+1 would help?

Comment: The limit does not exist along those paths.

Comment: Still not getting it. Substituting y=x+1 makes it (x+1)/x. How will this help?

Comment: @joeylang As $x\to0$, $y\to1$. Right? And as $x\to0$,$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x+1}x\right)\ne\lim_{x\to0^-}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x+1}x\right)$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @joeylang No problem $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{t\to 0}\arctan (\frac {t^2+1}{t^2})=\frac{\pi}{2} $$

$$\lim_{t\to 0}\arctan (\frac {t^2+1}{-t^2})=-\frac {\pi}{2} $$

Your limit does not exist.

Comment: >_> Almost a copycat of my answer... =P

Comment: What did you substitute?

Comment: @joeylang the paths are $y=t^2+1$ and $x=\pm t^2$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt just almost.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help